# How can this work?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

Please see this txid : https://etherscan.io/tx/0x475743c4b17542b52c91d642a130af89f4ec7ca41eb43fc00fa788465a2b6c13

How can this work.
I see this only does one transaction, but why can the address receive so many tokens from the subcontract and etc. ?

Comment: nice catch. it is interesting situation, because all tokens were transferred to one address https://etherscan.io/address/0xa9830a917f71925007b359d61c3dcb7d23b08750

Comment: I think this is nice contract, but I can't build like this. :D haha

Answer (score 1):

It looks like he has a contract, which creates 26 other contracts, which trigger a transfer in RedRabbitToken (follow the internal transactions). All Transfer events + some other events are written to the transaction receipt. No idea what the logic behind all this is, since there is no source code attached, but in general, you can always have a contract directly or indirectly calling the transfer function of an ERC20 multiple times.